# Search without conditions if no results are returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, dry, repeat

I am trying to search a table and find the first item that matches some conditions, and **if no results** are returned **repeat the query removing some conditions**.

As I have two parameters right now, I ended with an OR condition of 4 different searches. That works but it doesn't seem very DRY, efficient or scalable to me... And it can only go worse, as I'm expecting to add dates to the conditions too.

```
Item.where(cond1: cond1, cond2: cond2).first ||
Item.where(cond1: cond1, cond2: nil).first ||
Item.where(cond1: nil, cond2: cond2).first ||
Item.where(cond1: nil, cond2: nil).first
```

Is there some way to do that kind of search on a clever way?

Thank you

Comment: What if results are found?  End with the first result?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to keep the first (more specific) result you find.

Comment: I personally like to read my code as paragraphs.  It is better and cleaner to show the business logic instead of hiding it in the syntax.  Simple if-statements with queries would be my route.

Comment: Thanks :). Anyway, I'm more interested on finding a way (if it's possible) to avoid 4 queries on the worst case (or even more if I add more conditionals). Also, I have simplified the queries there to be clear, but the first ones have a join on them.

Comment: You can avoid 4 queries only if you do it on the DB side. Stored Proc or something similar, but I do not think that it is worth it. Just code it cleanly.

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea... But as you say, I don't think it is worth it. I'm not an expert on Ruby on Rails, so I was expecting some kind of RoR magic... and maybe there isn't a better way to do it and my code is not that bad (well, just only a bit)

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb maybe you should put your last comment as an answer. Right now it seems to me the best possible answer and could be of some help to someone looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid four queries only if you do it on the DB side. Stored Proc or something similar, but I do not think that it is worth it.  Just code it cleanly

Answer (score 0):

I would make a method that returns an item and gets a list of items and a list of predicates (condition functions) as input parameters. If the search with all conditions finds nothing, call it recursively with one condition removed. Logic may vary (you can do combinations of conditions instead of removing them one by one)

Comment: I like the idea of the recursive function, will try it to check if it ends on a nicer solution... but that does not solve the main issue (new db query every time) :(

Comment: the problem here is that you're trying to get the most specific set of conditions that match something, and AFAIK there's no way of doing that without successive tries

Comment: Yes, it seems that there is not a better way to do it and I will have to stick with the sequential searches.